# How to calculate percentil from percentil subresults

Tags: percentile

I would like to calculate the 90th percentile, for example `p90` for this dataset:

```
p90(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10) = 9.1
```

Problem is that due to technical limitations I don't have whole dataset available for the calculation and only partial subset (of random size) of whole dataset is processed by n-workers and each worker generates own p90 subresult, e.g. 2 workers:

```
worker 1: p90(1, 2, 3) = 2.8
worker 2: p90(4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10) = 9.4
```

Is it possible to calculate `p90` of whole dataset from these worker `p90` subresults somehow? I can generate additional metrics by worker, e.g. `count` if it helps.
I can calculate result for `sum/min/max/avg/count` functions from these worker `sum/min/max/avg/count` subresults, but I'm struggling with percentiles. Is it possible?

Comment: What definition of percentile are you using? With the one I'm familiar with, I thought the percentile has to be in the set itself

Comment: @StephenDonovan Actually, 'percentile' in this case is a Cribl `perc` aggregation function (https://docs.cribl.io/stream/aggregations-function/#list-of-aggregate-functions) - source code is not available. It is used in the monitoring world, so it should be `The p90 latency is the highest latency value (slowest response) of the fastest 90 percent of requests. In other words, 90 percent of requests have responses that are equal to or faster than the p90 latency value`